# Laravel parameter issue

Tags: php, laravel

Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\Company\OrderController::store()

I got this error in my store controller, my form is passing 2 parameters but the second one is not found.

Route: Route::resource('order', 'OrderController');
$company gets converted to a model in the controller.

The form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{action('Company\OrderController@store', [$company,$orderid])}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created `store` route with `Route::resource()` it doesn't expect any parameters and should look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

So, you need to pass data using hidden inputs, like:

```
{!! Form::hidden('data', 'some data') !!}
```

And then get data in controller with:

```
$data = $request->data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `key-value` pair like this:

```
['company_id' => $company->id, 'order_id' => $order->id]
```

So your form would look like:

```
<form action="{{ action('Company\OrderController@store', ['company_id' => $company->id, 'order_id' => $order->id]) }}">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>

</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will not work, since `store()` will not pass any parameters. You can look at generated route with `php artisan route:list` command.